# How to check database for matching results in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I want to be able to select matching data from my database, to then decide which code to be executed, specifically, I don't want users to be able to sign up twice with the same username.

I've tried what you would normally try, posting the information in the controller and passing it to the model for it to be counted. Then I tried what I've seen many people use, the `num_rows();`.

```
controller.php


$userchecker = $_POST['register-username'];
$this->load->model('User_exists');
$this->User_exists->usercheck($userchecker);

            if ($usercheck > 0) {

              echo '<p style="color: orange;">A user with this username already exists!</p>';
              exit();

            }

            else {

//Insert user

model.php


public function usercheck($userchecker) {

$this->db->where('ci_useruid', $userchecker);
$query = $this->db->get('users');

$result = $query->result();
$usercheck = $result->num_rows();
}
```

What I expect to happen is for the model to check if the user exists based on the information passed on from the controller, and if so, throw an error. Otherwise, go on to insert as usual.

The error I get is:

> Call to a member function num_rows() on array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check how many rows are in the DB with the specific user name

**Model**

```
public function usercheck($userchecker) {
    return $this->db->get_where('ci_useruid', ['ci_useruid' => $userchecker])->num_rows();
}
```

**Controller**

Based on the result of the function `usercheck` do what you want

```
$userchecker = $_POST['register-username'];
$this->load->model('User_exists');
$rows = $this->User_exists->usercheck($userchecker);

if ($rows > 0) {
    echo '<p style="color: orange;">A user with this username already exists!</p>';
    exit();
}else {
   //Coding...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing things up

```
$query = $this->db->get('users');

$result = $query->result();
$usercheck = $result->num_rows();
```

your `$query` variable holds the whole result object. Thus it's `$query` who holds `->result()`, `->num_rows()`, etc.

By assigning `$result` with `$query->result()` you are assigning the array of objects you got from the database, but not the helper methods (such as `num_rows()` which still live within `$query`)

That said, a much simpler approach to avoiding duplicate usernames is to use the `form_validation` method in this way:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field description', 'required|is_unique[tablename.fieldname]');
```

then run the form validation in the controller and you won't need to handle the uniqueness yourself

Comment: Then it says `Unknown column 'register-username' in 'where clause'`  where `register-username` is the field name or input name.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to this.

```
$this->db->where('ci_useruid', $userchecker);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$usercheck = $query->num_rows();
```

you can have a simpler way to that and it was already mentioned by @Javier Larroulet. using the form validation `is_unique`.

just load these helper and library:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

then you are set to go.